# User control CalendarPopup inside a GridView is not refreshed when inside an UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, ajax, gridview, webforms, user-controls

I'm using the eWorldUI Calendar Popup (link at bottom) inside a GridView inside an UpdatePanel.

If I don't put my page form content inside an UpdatePanel, the calendar is refreshed fine when I update a row of the Gridview. However, when everything is inside an UpdatePanel, the calendar is not refreshed, so it always keep the ID of the first row calendar.

My question is:

What is the difference between GridView controls "within UpdatePanel" and "outside of UpdatePanel" and is there any reasons why the event of the control that generates the calendar HTML would not happen at all or not happen at the right moment after I update a row of the gridview inside an UpdatePanel ? 
Tips on fixing the issue are also appreciated :)

Here is a sample code (please note that the gridview datasource is set in the code behind)

```
<html>
<head> <!-- head stuff --> </head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:scriptmanager id="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:scriptmanager>
<asp:updatepanel id="UpdatePanel1" runat="server"><contenttemplate>
<asp:gridview id="GRIDVIEW1" showheader="False" showfooter="False" runat="server" autogeneratecolumns="false" onrowdatabound="GridView_RowDataBound">                               
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <HeaderTemplate> ...    </HeaderTemplate>
        <HeaderStyle cssclass="..."></HeaderStyle>
        <FooterTemplate> ... </FooterTemplate>
        <FooterStyle cssclass="..."></FooterStyle>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:textbox id="GRIDVIEW1_DATE1" text="<%# Bind('GRIDVIEW1_DATE1') %>" runat="server"></asp:textbox>
            <ew:calendarpopup imageurl="../../App_Themes/Images/calendar.gif" controldisplay="Image" id="GRIDVIEW1_DATE1_CAL" runat="server"></ew:calendarpopup>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label id="GRIDVIEW1_DATE1" runat="server" text='<%# Bind("GRIDVIEW1_DATE1") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemStyle cssclass="..."></ItemStyle>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:CommandField buttontype="Button" showdeletebutton="True" showeditbutton="True" causesvalidation="False" insertvisible="False"></asp:CommandField>
</Columns>
</asp:gridview>
</contenttemplate></asp:updatepanel>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the calendar in question - http://www.eworldui.net/CustomControls/CalendarPopupDemo.aspx

**Edit**

I found out that my issue is actually because the dynamic HTML generated by the calendar is in fact inside the `<form>`, but it is added outside the UpdatePanel. It wasn't obvious because as you can see, everything seems inside the UpdatePanel. So to test it, I have added a `<div class="outsideUpdatePanel"></div>` outside the UpdatePanel and when launching in Chrome and inspecting the HTML, I could see that the generated calendar HTML appears after my new div.

Comment: I'm sorry if it seems specific, I could ask the same thing in general with any controls, so the anwser doesn't have to be about the Calendar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in the GridView in or out of an Updatepanel.
The Full page life cycle happens in both cases.
The only difference is that only the contents of the UpdatePanel's ContentTemplate is transmitted back to the browser.

You don't specify the Gridview `DataSourceID` property so you have to manage the databinds.  Make sure you are rebinding the GridView after the Update.

And also I have to ask this because I can't see your datasource field list, But does it actually contain a field called *GRIDVIEW1_DATE1*? I just want to confirm that you don't mean to bind to the Gridview TextBox control by using it's ID

EDIT: Also, Just FYI, if you are developing for HTML5, you can just set the TextBox `TextMode` property to *Date* and use the built in calendar popup of modern browsers. (`Text` property must be formatted as *yyyy-mm-dd*)

Comment: Yes, I do have a column in my table that's equal to the ID. That's also what I have read about the life cycle, so the only reason I see currently is that it must mean that the html of the calendar control is not added to the UpdatePanel.

Comment: I didn't solve my issue yet, but your post does anwser my question. Now I know why it doesn't update, so I'll update my post with the steps taken.

Comment: i don't see any binding for the control, meaning i don't see anyway for the control to populate the associated textbox or vice-versa to show a starting point for user selection...today's date or something similar.  Is that all being managed in the code behind?

Comment: Yes it is, sorry I could not put this part of the code because it's a bit messy in there but all the binding is working fine anyway. I have updated my post.

Comment: FYI - jquery makes it easy to move DOM objects.  I had to do something similar to make ColorBox (third party popup) work with ASP.NET.   This moves 2 div's that were rendered outside the form to inside the botton of the form : `$("#colorbox, #cboxOverlay").appendTo('form:first');`.